# Odd size numbered MutableList<Int> in Kotlin returns IndexOutOfBoundsException with iterator

Tags: exception, iterator, kotlin

Running a test with the code below returns a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 75, Size: 75.

This does not happen on even numbered lists, only odd numbered lists. Am I doing this wrong? Iterating in Java does not seem to do this.

```
var mList: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
for(n in 1..75) {
    mList.add(n)
}
for(n in mList.iterator()) {
    println(mList[n])
}
```

Comment: `1..75` is an inclusive range. The 75th element is added to the list at index 74.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mList` contains these numbers, with these indexes:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 73, 74, 75]   list contents
  0  1  2  3  ...   72  73  74    indexes
```

Therefore, if you index `mList` with the contents of `mList` itself, that means accessing indexes `1` through `75`, which will give you the numbers 2 through 75 for the first 74 accesses, and finally an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when you try to access the element at index `75`, which doesn't exist.

If you want to iterate over `mList` and print its elements, you have several ways to do that:

```
// using indexes with `until`
for(i in 0 until mList.size) { println(mList[i]) }

// using `.indices` to get the start and end indexes
for(i in mList.indices) { println(mList[i]) }

// range-for loop
for(i in mList) { println(i) }

// functional approach
mList.forEach { println(it) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over all numbers `1..75` but indexing starts at 0. Subtracting `1` from the item would give you the correct index to the value.

```
for(n in mList.iterator()) {
    println(mList[n - 1])
}
```

But eventually it's not even what you intended to do at all. You might want to print the item directly or iterate over the indices `0..mList.size-1` itself.

Comment: Ahh I see. I thought that by calling the iterator I was referencing N as the index of the iterator, not the value. Thank makes sense. Because my list is not based on 0 being the starting value and N being the value instead of the index, it will overflow.